# How to create MSForms ListBox in Worksheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, activex, ms-forms

I'm trying to create a list box of the type `MSForms.ListBox` programmatically using VBA.

I can't do it with `Set ListBox = New MSForms.ListBox` because it throws the compile error: [`Invalid use of the New keyword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-use-of-new-keyword).

In the code below when I create an [`OLEObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobject) in `Macro1` it creates `VBAProject.Sheet1.ListBox1` (or other number) which I can then (after execution has ended) assign in `Macro2` to a variable of type `MSForms.ListBox` but it only works if I run one macro at a time.

With a `MSForms.ListBox` I can then change properties like `ListBox.ColumnHeads = True` (even though I don't know how to change the head value other than addressing the list values to a range with `ListBox.ListFillRange = RangeAddress`).

If I try to execute the code step by step I get the message [`Can't enter break mode at this time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/can-t-enter-break-mode-at-this-time).

I got `OLEObject` from recording a macro and [inserting a List Box ActiveX Control](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/list-box.html).

```
' Microsoft Excel 2013 built-in references:
' Excel - Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library
' VBA - Visual Basic For Applications

' VBA project library:
' VBAProject

' Aditional references:
' MSForms - Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

Private Sub Macro1()

  Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim ListBox As Excel.ListBox
  Dim Shape As Excel.Shape
  Dim OLEObject As Excel.OLEObject

  Set Worksheet = VBAProject.Sheet1
  Worksheet.Range("A1").Value = "Header"
  Worksheet.Range("A2").Value = "Value 1"
  Worksheet.Range("A3").Value = "Value 2"
  Worksheet.Range("A4").Value = "Value 3"

  For Each Shape In Worksheet.Shapes
    Shape.Delete
  Next Shape

  Set ListBox = Worksheet.ListBoxes.Add(60, 10, 100, 100)
  ListBox.List = Array("Header", "Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3")
  ListBox.ListFillRange = "A1:A4"

  Set OLEObject = Worksheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1", Link:=False, Left:=170, Top:=10, Width:=100, Height:=100)
  OLEObject.ListFillRange = "A1:A4"

  Set Shape = Worksheet.Shapes.AddOLEObject(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1", Link:=False, Left:=280, Top:=10, Width:=100, Height:=100)

End Sub

Private Sub Macro2()

  Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim ListBox As MSForms.ListBox

  Set Worksheet = Excel.Application.ActiveSheet

  Set ListBox = VBAProject.Sheet1.ListBox1
  ListBox.ListFillRange = ""
  ListBox.List = Array("Header", "Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3")
  ListBox.ColumnHeads = True
  ListBox.ListFillRange = "A1:A4"
  ListBox.BorderStyle = MSForms.fmBorderStyle.fmBorderStyleSingle

End Sub
```

---

**Edit:**

Simple working example using the solution given in the accepted answer:

```
Private Function CreateListBox( _
  Optional ByVal Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing, _
  Optional ByVal Width As Long = 100, _
  Optional ByVal Height As Long = 100, _
  Optional ByVal Left As Long = 0, _
  Optional ByVal Top As Long = 0 _
  ) As MSForms.ListBox

  Const ClassType As String = "Forms.ListBox.1"

  If Worksheet Is Nothing Then
    Set Worksheet = Excel.Application.ActiveSheet
  End If

  Set CreateListBox = Worksheet.OLEObjects.Add( _
    ClassType, _
    Left:=Left, _
    Top:=Top, _
    Width:=Width, _
    Height:=Height).Object

End Function

Private Sub Test()

  Dim ListBox As MSForms.ListBox

  Set ListBox = CreateListBox
  Stop ' Able to stop/suspend code execution here but not inside the function when creating the OLEObject

End Sub
```

Comment: [This](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/complete-guide-to-excel-vba-form-control-listboxes/#add) might help

Comment: @Zac I have seen that but it creates an `Excel.ListBox` which has different properties than the ones I want to change.

Comment: In short you want to run both the above macros in one go? i.e create an activex listbox and then set it's poperties?

Comment: You shouldn't create a variable named `Shape`, as that is a defined object type.

Comment: @PeterT I am aware that it goes against naming conventions / best practices as it overwrites `Shape` even thought I access the object type with `Excel.Shape`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Pretty much. Preferably in a simple way.

Comment: Oh it is pretty simple then... one moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press `.` within the `With lb...End With` code block, you will see that the intellisense does not reveal certain properties for example `.ColumnHeads`, `.BorderStyle` or `.List`. You can access those properties by prefixing it with `.Object`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim lb As OLEObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheet1

    For Each lb In ws.OLEObjects
        lb.Delete
    Next lb

    Set lb = ws.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1", _
                               Top:=60, _
                               Left:=10, _
                               Height:=100, _
                               Width:=100)

    With lb
        .ListFillRange = "'" & ws.Name & "'!A1:A16" '<~~ Change range here
        '.Object.List = Array("Header", "Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3")
        .Object.ColumnHeads = True
        .Object.BorderStyle = MSForms.fmBorderStyle.fmBorderStyleSingle
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: That's it! I did tried something similar before but didn't got it working. That way I can assign `lb.Object` to a variable of type `MSForms.ListBox` as well. Thank you :)